# passing variable between functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

if i have two functions that been called from ajax 
and i want to pass what ever the first function return to a variable in the other and use it only just once ONLY ONE TIME

the code bellow loop with the returnResult() function $.each() 
and some of the json data are missing like there is no text in the "labe" : {}

```
 $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "WebService.asmx/MyEventData",
          data: "{}",
          dataType: "json",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          success: function(data) {
          returnResult(data.d);  
         }

      });

       $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "WebService.asmx/Getlines",
          data: "{}",
          dataType: "json",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          success: function(data) {
              lineReturn(data.d);
          }

      });



      });

      function lineReturn(result) {
      var jsonObj = [] ; 
      $.each(result, function(index, value) {
         jsonObj.push({ "value": value.dateTime, "color": '#D2691E', "width": 1,    "label": { "text": value.LineEvent} });
      });
      return JSON.stringify(jsonObj) ; << this is the return that should go to myline variable and be used on the highchart >>>> 

  }

      function returnResult(result) {
      console.log(result) ;
      var myLine = lineReturn(result) ;
      var datetemp = new Array ;
      var dateflow = new Array ;
      var datepressure = new Array;
      var datecond = new Array ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the 2nd ajax call in the callback of the 1st.

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "WebService.asmx/Getlines",
      data: "{}",
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: function(dataA) {
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "WebService.asmx/MyEventData",
               data: "{}",
               dataType: "json",
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               success: function(dataB) {
                   // From here you can access both dataA.d and dataB.d
                   var myLineA = lineReturn(dataA.d);
                   var myLineB = lineReturn(dataB.d);
              }
           });
      }
});
```

Comment: okay can i at the second sucess add a function like this                 function dosomething(dataA.d, dataB.d){ then $.each(dataA ....   then $.each(dataB ...... is thats possible

Comment: @MinaGabriel: That should work.  In the 2nd success, you can access both `dataA` and `dataB`.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the second function on `.success` of the first function.